# Process timespan for each start/end pair using Hive script

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, data-analysis

I have a service that can be started or stopped. Each operation generates a record with timestamp and operation type. Ultimately, I end up with a series of timestamped operation records. Now I want to calculate the up-time of the service during a day. The idea is simple. For each pair of start/stop records, compute the timespan and sum up. But I don't know how to implement it with Hive, if possible at all. It's OK that I create tables to store intermediate results for this. This is the main blocking issue, and there are some other minor issues as well. For example, some start/stop pairs may span across a single day. Any idea how to deal with this minor issue would be appreciated too.

**Sample Data:**

```
Timestamp                Operation
...                      ...
2017-09-03 23:59:00      Start
2017-09-04 00:01:00      Stop
2017-09-04 06:50:00      Start
2017-09-04 07:00:00      Stop
2017-09-05 08:00:00      Start
...                      ...
```

The service up-time for `2017-09-04` should then be `1 + 10 = 11` mins. Note that the first time interval spans across `09-03` and `09-04`, and only the part that falls within `09-04` is counted.

Comment: can you give some examples about input/output?

Comment: Add a data sample (~10 rows), including required result, both in table format.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Added an example, and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      to_date(from_ts)                                                    as dt
           ,sum (to_unix_timestamp(to_ts) - to_unix_timestamp(from_ts)) / 60    as up_time_minutes

from       (select      case when pe.i = 0                       then from_ts else cast(date_add(to_date(from_ts),i)   as timestamp) end    as from_ts
                       ,case when pe.i = datediff(to_ts,from_ts) then to_ts   else cast(date_add(to_date(from_ts),i+1) as timestamp) end    as to_ts

            from       (select  `operation`
                               ,`Timestamp`                                     as from_ts
                               ,lead(`Timestamp`) over (order by `Timestamp`)   as to_ts

                        from    t
                        ) t

                        lateral view    posexplode(split(space(datediff(to_ts,from_ts)),' ')) pe as i,x

            where       `operation` = 'Start'
                    and to_ts is not null
            ) t

group by    to_date(from_ts) 
;
```

---

```
+------------+-----------------+
|     dt     | up_time_minutes |
+------------+-----------------+
| 2017-09-03 | 1.0             |
| 2017-09-04 | 11.0            |
+------------+-----------------+
```